# Make awk use character classes

Tags: regex, awk, character-class

How do I make awk recognise character classes?

For example, this:

```
echo "a\n1\nb\n2\nc" | awk '/1/'
```

outputs `1` as expected, but this:

```
echo "a\n1\nb\n2\nc" | awk '/\d/'
```

outputs nothing where I expected both `1` and `2` to survive the filter.

I thought this might be something to do with shell escaping (zsh) but `awk '/\\d/'` also doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for this question! I just spent 20 minutes trying to figure out why my awk 1-liner wasn't working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try using spelled-out character classes:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ printf "a\n1\nb\n2\nc\n" | awk '/[[:digit:]]/'
1
2
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

As far as I'm aware, notation like `\d` isn't actually part of ERE, which is the regex dialect understood by most awk variants (as well as [The One True Awk](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk)).

---

**UPDATE**:

As was pointed out in comments, some distributions of Linux may have [`mawk`](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/) installed, masquerading as `awk`.  mawk is NOT the same as awk. It is a minimal-featured awk clone, designed for execution speed rather than functionality.  And despite [claims in its man page](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/manpage/mawk.html#h3-3_-Regular-expressions) that it supports Extended Regular Expressions, mawk fails to implement POSIX "classes", like `[:digit:]`, `[:upper:]`, `[:lower:]`, etc.

If you run systems that provide non-standard tools like `mawk` in place of standard ones, then you should expect to live in interesting times. A developer of Awk scripts expects any binary at `/usr/bin/awk` to behave like awk. If it does not, the system is broken.

Comment: @sierrasdetandil - yep, mawk's inexplicable failure in this area is long standing, and has been the subject of [a number of repair attempts](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mawk/+bug/69724). My best advice to mawk users would be .. be aware of your tools, and if you like using POSIX character classes in your regexes, then don't use mawk.

Comment: Actually, POSIX character classes (i.e. [[:digit:]]) don't work with mawk < 1.3.4, and many distros currently ship with 1.3.3 (checked latest stable Debian, Ubuntu, Mandriva). Refs: [mawk: please implement POSIX-style character classes](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=65617); [Mawk does not support Posix character classes in expressions](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mawk/+bug/69724); http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149059/29395.

Comment: @ghoti True. Unfortunately, mawk (1.3.3) is the default awk in Ubuntu and Debian.

Comment: Ah, my condolences. Fortunately for me, use FreeBSD. :-) The last Ubuntu I used was 10.04, which had gawk 3.1.6 installed as awk. Are you sure you can't, say, install `gawk` using your package system? `apt-cache search gawk` in Ubuntu does seem to indicate that it's an available package. You don't *need* to use the default tools, do you?

Comment: @ghoti I've already installed it and _I_ don't need to use the default tools, but I can't always dictate what's in other people's systems :-). I was writing a script that's going to be used by coworkers (mostly *buntu users), and wanted to avoid having to add a comment at the top stating "Requires gawk. Run `sudo apt-get install gawk`." Finally went for plain old character lists instead of character classes, in the name of portability.

Comment: @sierrasdetandil, thanks for your comments. I've updated my answer for clarification. While I feel your pain re your coworkers, might I suggest moving to [an operating system that does things more sensibly](https://www.over-yonder.net/~fullermd/rants/bsd4linux/01)? :-)

Comment: @ghoti Nice update, thank you! Re BSD, I tried a couple of variants in a VM some time ago, but I'll stick to Linux for now, for several reasons. You're right, though, the differences between Linux distros can be annoying, to say the least.